# Example for Propogation type nested not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to test `Propagation.NESTED` for spring-boot, I configured my project like below:
Driver class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class Launcher {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

below is my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class Ex_TranscationRollBackStrategy {
  @Nested
    @DisplayName("nested txn with propagation NESTED")
    class NestedWithNestedPropagation{

        @Test
        @DisplayName("add product but exception while creating an order but with propagation NESTED")
        public void productOrderWithExceptionButNotSupported(){
            Product product = Product.builder()
                    .description("product description")
                    .price(0)
                    .title("some title")
                    .build();
            try {
                productService.addProductAndOrderWithExceptionWithNestedForOrder(product);
            }catch (RuntimeException re){
                System.err.println(re.getMessage());
            }

            List<Product> productList = StreamSupport
                    .stream(productRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                    .collect(toList());

            List<ProductOrder> productOrderList = StreamSupport
                    .stream(orderRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                    .collect(toList());
            assertEquals(1, productOrderList.size());
            assertEquals(0, productList.size());

        }
    }
}
```

Below are my model classes:

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private String title;
    private int price;

}
```

and `Order` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProductOrder")
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductOrder {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;
}
```

and below are my service class:

```
@Service
//@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ProductService {
    @Transactional
    public void addProductAndOrderWithExceptionWithNestedForOrder(Product product) {

        productRepository.save(product);
        ProductOrder productOrder = ProductOrder.builder()
                .title("some order")
                .description("some testing order")
                .build();
        orderService.addOrderWithExceptionWithTxnNested(productOrder);
    }
}
```

and `OrderService`

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class OrderService {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public void addOrderWithExceptionWithTxnNested(ProductOrder productOrder) {
        orderRepository.save(productOrder);
        throw new RunTimeException();
    }
}
```

I expected the `productOrderList` size to be 1, but it came to 0.

Comment: You have read-only transaction in OrderService class. Hence nothing will be inserted in the DB.

Comment: @Mar-Z I have overriden it inside the method, hence that will take priority